# Doctrine 2 SQL Server query (MSSQL / SQLSRV) (WiTH DISTINCT)

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine, group-by, distinct

**Hi Guys! Thank you for the quick response of all.
I am working with Doctrine 2. In it, I did the following query:**

```
$qb =    $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('obj.objRowid')
                ->from('MapAdminCaminhoCriticoIndicadores', 'cci')

                ->innerJoin('cci.cciIndicadordr', 'ind')
                ->innerJoin('cci.cciCaminhodr', 'ccr')
                ->innerJoin('ind.indObjetivodr', 'obj')

                ->groupBy('obj.objRowid')

                ->getQuery();
```

**Return correct (grouped) for echo 'objRowid':**

```
2
4
11
```

**Now, I insert the column 'cci.cciRowid' in 'select' and 'GroupBy':**

```
$qb =    $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('obj.objRowid, cci.cciRowid')
                ->from('MapAdminCaminhoCriticoIndicadores', 'cci')

                ->innerJoin('cci.cciIndicadordr', 'ind')
                ->innerJoin('cci.cciCaminhodr', 'ccr')
                ->innerJoin('ind.indObjetivodr', 'obj')

                ->groupBy('obj.objRowid, cci.cciRowid')

                ->getQuery();
```

**Return without group, repeating the value '4 ':**

```
2
4
4
11
```

**Do you have any idea? Thanks guys!!! ;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're second query selects two columns, but you only show one in your output. I suspect the 4 is repeating for `obj.objRowid` because there are different two values for `cci.cciRowid` when `obj.objRowid` is 4.

Comment: That's right @Joe, cci.cciRowid is primary key (auto-increment) and never repeats. However, I need it and can not get obj.objRowid repeated. Thank you!!!

Comment: @WillianTeodoro How would you decide which of the two values for `cci.cciRowId` would be returned? You could, for example, select the `MIN(cci.cciRowId)` and GROUP BY only `obj.objRowid`.

Comment: I need more columns in the select. If I do what you said, it displays the message that the column does not exist. And if I put the column, gives the group by error: Column 'map_admin_caminho_critico_indicadores.CCI_RowID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Any other columns you add to the SELECT that are not participating in an aggregate function (e.g., MIN) must be included in the GROUP BY clause as well.

Comment: Then go back to square one. The values ​​'4 'for obj.objRowid repeat.

Comment: `->select('MIN(cci.cciRowid), cci.cciRowid')
      ->groupBy('obj.objRowid, cci.cciRowid')`

Comment: @WillianTeodoro I'd really need more information about exactly which columns you're trying to return now. It would probably require a more complicated query with a subquery to solve.

Comment: Thank you, @JoeStefanelli! I found the solution to solve using your tip, with minor adjustment: `->select('obj.objRowid, obj.objObjetivo, MIN(cci.cciRowid) AS cciRowid')... ->groupBy('obj.objRowid, obj.objObjetivo')` THANK YOU Again!!! ;)